# How does the UIView.animate function internally work?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I implemented a simple animation with:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.heading.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
}
```

And it magically does the right thing: moves the heading textfield back to the center of the frame in half a second. But how does it figure out which properties I am changing in the closure and how does it change it with a increment based on timing?

Knowing this would help me understand how to replicate such implementation for other use cases, not just animations.